# Location directive not matching as intended

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make any request that lacks a file extension be directed to my express server, apart from `/` and `/dashboard`, which I want to go to my connect server. `/dashboard` is supposed to request `/dashboard.html` from the connect server. Here's what I have:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver;

    index index.html;

    location @connect {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
    }

    location @express {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9002;
    }

    location ~* \.(html|js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        try_files $uri @connect;
        expires 7d;
    }

    location = / {
        try_files $uri @connect;
    }

    location = /dashboard {
        try_files $uri.html @connect;
    }    

    location / {
        try_files $uri @express;
    }
}
```

`/` goes to the connect server as intended, but `/dashboard` goes to my express server. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide `curl -I http://your_server/dashboard`?

Comment: @VBart I get a 404 error, I still get a 404 if I kill the express server. Perhaps it's going to express only after not finding the file from the connect server? Which would mean the directive is being matched, I'm just doing something wrong inside it? I've added more detail about what I'm trying to do in the post.

Comment: Yes, you're doing it wrong. Your request `/dashboard` goes to `@connect` as is. Why do you use `try_files` at all? You should just replace it with `proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/dashboard.html;`.

Comment: Look at the docs carefully: http://nginx.org/r/try_files

Comment: @VBart Thanks a lot, that works perfectly. Could you post your solution as an answer so I can award you the bounty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to replace:

```
location = /dashboard {
    try_files $uri.html @connect;
}
```

with

```
location = /dashboard {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/dashboard.html;
}
```

Reference:

- http://nginx.org/r/try_files
- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because you used `location = /dashboard` and i believe that this for example won't match `/dashboard/`, do u want only the exact location to match? i mean why not use `location /dashboard/` ( removing the `=` )

Comment: Yep, I only want that location to match. Removing the `=` doesn't fix the problem.